# How can I restart game timer from where it left off after pausing game?

Tags: ios, objective-c, timer

I’m doing a word game in Xcode 9.3 & Objective-C.

I have the game installed on my phone with iOS 11.3.1 and if I get a phone call while in the game it is displaced by the call. Then after the call the game reappears and is resumed right where it left off. All that without adding any code.

I’m trying to do the same when the game is interrupted by the user e.g. pressing home button.

So I have;

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"stopTimer" object:self];
}
```

And:

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"startTimer" object:self];
}
```

And because

```
@interface ViewController ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) WRWGameController* controller;
@end
```

In game controller I have

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(stopTimer)        
                                            name:@"stopTimer"
                                          object:nil];
```

And

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(startTimer)
                                             name:@"startTimer"
                                           object:nil];
```

The timer stops in the inactive state but when the game is resumed the timer starts again at 00.00.

I’ve looked at various stop and start timer posts here but haven’t found a way to incorporate the code in my app so the timer starts up again where it left off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to save the start time to an NSDate instance variable:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDate *startTime;
```

Then save the date to it in the startTimer method:

```
self.startTime = [NSDate date];
```

Then when you stop the timer, you can get the elapsed time using

```
NSTimeInterval elapsedTime = -[self.startTime timeIntervalSinceNow];
```

When you restart your time, simply deduct the elapsedTime from the interval you're using in the timer.